# Include local jar into maven

Tags: maven-plugin, setup-project

My application is having 70 jars with ant application. Now we are moving ant to maven, but i am unable not find 10 jars (Local jars) in maven repository.

Shell we import 10 jars manually.(I read somewhere that if you include more jars manullay don't choose maven, is it correct?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to use Maven, jars must be fetched from `$HOME/.m2` local repository. If those missing 10 jars are individual maven projects with a `pom.xml` & you had run `maven install` in each one of their project folder, i see no reason why those jars are not there in your local repo.